# Как решить проблему с mustache и spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mustache

Я делаю свой первый проект со spring boot. Когда я загружаю страницу с базой данных, она выглядит так:

> [{"dietaId":1,"nazwa":"Antycellulitowa","opis":"Na początku
>   chcielibyśmy omówić podstawowe zasady omawianego tutaj programu
>   żywieniowego. Przede wszystkim, dobrze jest jeść mało, lecz często.
>   Niezwykle istotne jest także regularne przyjmowanie posiłków i nie
>   omijanie żadnego z nich (szczególnie śniadań, które powinny dostarczać
>   nam niezbędnej energii na resztę dnia). Dieta antycellulitowa powinna
>   być odpowiednio zbilansowana i bogata w nieprzetworzone, świeże
>   produkty (zwłaszcza warzywa i owoce). Najlepiej unikać jest potraw
>   smażonych i duszonych w tłustych lub śmietanowych sosach. Zamiast
>   tego, dobrze jest przygotowywać posiłki poprzez gotowanie na parze lub
>   pieczenie.\r\n\r\nNiezwykle istotnym zaleceniem diety antycellulitowej
>   jest rezygnacja lub znaczne ograniczenie soli, gdyż zatrzymuje ona w
>   naszym organizmie wodę i toksyny. Zamiast tej przyprawy, możemy
>   spokojnie sięgać po świeże zioła, czosnek, cebulę, bazylię, estragon,
>   oregano itp. Nasze menu powinno składać się z chudego mięsa, drobiu,
>   ryb oraz nabiału. Możemy także jak najczęściej sięgać po cytrusy,
>   które wspomagają odtwarzanie wpływających na poprawę wyglądu skóry
>   włókien kolagenu. Polecamy zapoznanie się z artykułem dotyczącym diety
>   grapefruitowej, która jest jednym z najbardziej skutecznych programów
>   żywieniowych wspomagających walkę ze skórką pomarańczową. Podczas
>   walki z cellulitem świetnie sprawdzają się także działające
>   przeciwobrzękowo produkty bogate w potas, w tym sałata, pomidory i
>   ziemniaki. Warto sięgać również po witaminę B, którą znajdziemy w
>   jajach, drożdżach i kiełkach zbóż. Szczególnie ważne w walce ze skórką
>   pomarańczową są produkty zawierające kwasy tłuszczowe omega (np. oleje
>   roślinne, ryby, orzechy, oliwa) – usprawniają one metabolizm i
>   spalanie tkanek tłuszczowych.\r\n\r\nChcąc pozbyć się cellulitu, nie
>   możemy zapominać o piciu co najmniej 2 litrów mineralnej wody o
>   niskiej zawartości sodu. Wspomaga ona wydalanie z organizmu wszelkich
>   ubocznych produktów przemiany materii, które to przyczyniają się do
>   nasilenia efektu skórki pomarańczowej. Oprócz wody, dobrze jest pić
>   także czerwoną i zieloną herbatę (usprawnia metabolizm) oraz napary z
>   ziół. Zalecane są również wszystkie produkty działające moczopędnie a
>   wiec: arbuz, pietruszka, seler, czereśnie, truskawki.\r\n\r\nPodczas
>   stosowania diety antycellulitowej, należy unikać potraw tłustych i
>   mocno przyprawionych (w tym popularnych w dzisiejszych czasach dań
>   typu fast food). Zawierają one dużo soli i wysoko przetworzonych
>   produktów, które to są odradzane w każdym odpowiednio zbilansowanym
>   programie żywieniowym. Dobrze jest także ograniczyć słodycze i
>   alkohol. Od czasu do czasu można oczywiście sięgnąć po lampkę
>   czerwonego wina lub drink na bazie świeżo wyciśniętego soku, lecz
>   lepiej unikać wysokoprocentowych trunków. Jeżeli mamy ochotę na cos
>   słodkiego, najlepiej jest wybrać gorzką czekoladę o wysokiej
>   zawartości kakao. Unikajmy jednak cukru w czystej postaci, mlecznych
>   deserów a także słodzonych serków. Dobrze jest także ograniczyć lub
>   zupełnie wyeliminować z menu czerwone mięso, tłusty ser żółty, kawę
>   oraz wędliny. Z naszego jadłospisu należy definitywnie wykreślić
>   słodkie napoje gazowane.\r\n\r\nJak w jednym zdaniu można
>   scharakteryzować dietę antycellulitową? Jest to przede wszystkim
>   zdrowy i lekki program żywieniowy. Niezwykle istotny jest też fakt, że
>   korzyści z jego stosowania mogą być różnorodne – nie tylko znacznie
>   zredukujemy uporczywą skórkę pomarańczową, lecz dodatkowo możemy
>   poprawić wygląd naszej sylwetki i stan skóry. Pamiętajmy jednak, że
>   dieta będzie skuteczna tylko i wyłącznie wtedy, jeśli nie potraktujemy
>   jej jako metody doraźnej, lecz jako sposób odżywiania, który warto
>   stosować przez resztę naszego życia."},

DietaController.class:

```
@RestController
public class DietaController {
    @Autowired
    private DietaRepository dietaRepository;
    @GetMapping("/dieta")
    public List<Dieta> getAllNotes() {
        return dietaRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Dieta.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
<title>Diety</title>
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    padding: 5px;
}
 body {background-color: #ffffff;}
        h1 {

            font-size:  250%;
            color:#d52440;
        }
        p {

            font-size: 150%;
        }

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Diety</h1>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Numer</th>
            <th>Nazwa</th>
            <th>Opis</th>

        </tr>

        {{#diety}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{dietaId}}</td>
            <td>{{nazwa}}</td>
            <td>{{opis}}</td>

        </tr>
        {{/diety}}

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Dieta.class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "diety")
public class Dieta {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="DIETA_ID") private int dietaId;
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(unique=true, name ="DIETA_NAZWA")
    private String nazwa;
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="OPIS") private String opis;
    public Dieta(){ }
    public Dieta (int dietaId,String nazwa, String opis )
    { this.dietaId = dietaId;
    this.nazwa = nazwa;
    this.opis = opis; }
    public int getDietaId() {
        return dietaId; }
        public void setDietaId(int dietaId) {
        this.dietaId = dietaId; }
        public String getNazwa() {
        return nazwa; }
        public void setNazwa(String nazwa) {
        this.nazwa = nazwa; }
        public String getOpis() {
        return opis; }
        public void setOpis(String opis) {
        this.opis = opis; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Controller
public class DietaController {

```
@Autowired
private DietaRepository dietaRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/dieta", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String servicesList(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("diety", dietaRepository.findAll());
    return "dieta";
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Результат логичен, так как `DietaController` - REST-контроллер. Если в качестве ответа на запрос должна возвращаться HTML-страница, нужно, чтобы класс-контроллер имел аннотацию `@Controller`, а метод возвращал, например, объект класса `ModelAndView`, как описано [в документации](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-controller).

Должно получиться что-то вроде (JDK9+):

```java
@Controller
public class DietaController {

    @Autowired
    private DietaRepository dietaRepository;

    @GetMapping("/dieta")
    public ModelAndView getAllNotes() {
        return new ModelAndView("dieta", Map.of("diety", dietaRepository.findAll()));
    }
}
```

Первый аргумент конструктора `ModelAndView` - имя шаблона. Если используется Spring Boot с настройками по умолчанию, то соответствующий файл будет `src/main/resources/templates/dieta.html`

Comment: Это не работает

Comment: @LapkoKatia, что получается?

Comment: https://scontent-waw1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/83763338_174942390272464_1529987605624520704_n.png?_nc_cat=101&_nc_ohc=-nrBzWG7Gm8AX-aqaql&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.xx&oh=25aff9343cbc348403724881bb9fb6c2&oe=5ED109CE

Comment: @LapkoKatia, я же указал, что пример для JDK+) Тогда вместо `Map.of` можно использовать `Collections.singletonMap`

Comment: уже решила проблему, но спасибо большое :)